# Submit HTML form through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm experiencing a problem with my form. Im trying to post data to a PHP file using Ajax, but i stumbled across a problem with form validations.

*My Form*

```
<form id="kt_modal_new_target_form" class="form" name="kt_modal_new_target_form" method="post" action="test.php">
....
<button type="submit" id="kt_modal_new_target_submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="indicator-label">Submit</span>
</button>
</form>
```

Part of my Modal with form hander file (the part which validates the form.) As you see, after it validates the form, the is a form submit function, but i cant seem to make it work as ajax. I've tried *$.ajax*, I've tried submitting through the html file, but then it doesn't validate the form...

```
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Validate form before submit
        if (validator) {
            validator.validate().then(function (status) {
                console.log('validated!');

                if (status == 'Valid') {
                    submitButton.setAttribute('data-kt-indicator', 'on');

                    // Disable button to avoid multiple click 
                    submitButton.disabled = true;

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        submitButton.removeAttribute('data-kt-indicator');

                        // Enable button
                        submitButton.disabled = false;
                        
                        // Show success message. For more info check the plugin's official documentation: https://sweetalert2.github.io/
                        Swal.fire({
                            text: "Nurašymas atliktas!",
                            icon: "success",
                            buttonsStyling: false,
                            confirmButtonText: "Gerai!",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                            }
                        }).then(function (result) {
                            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                modal.hide();
                            }
                        });

                        form.submit(); // Submit form
                    }, 2000);                           
                } else {
                    // Show error message.
                    Swal.fire({
                        text: "Pildant nurašymą rasta klaidų, bandykite dar kartą.",
                        icon: "error",
                        buttonsStyling: false,
                        confirmButtonText: "Gerai!",
                        customClass: {
                            confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Anyone able to help me out? I need this form to validate through the **.js** file and then to send the data using Ajax to a **PHP** file.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't appear to attempt Ajax, but your question is asking about Ajax. Could you post the code you used when you attempted to use `$.ajax` as well as any errors you recieve in the JS console?

Comment: Try putting the ajax code into a function and then give the button an onclick="functionName()". And remove type="submit".This should work.